# macOS Sierra asks for non-existing SSH passphrase

Tags: terminal, mac, ssh

I'm having a strange problem in macOS Sierra, when trying to connect a remote server via SSH.

I have a key, which I have created it without passphrase. I can correctly connect to the server using that key with Putty (Windows) and CyberDuck (Mac).

However, when I try to connect via SSH using the command line (`ssh -I path/to/key user@server`) the system asks me for the passphrase.

Any idea what could be wrong? How could I connect with a key that doesn't have a passphrase?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just asking you for your account administrator's password? SSH typically required admin authorisation when run from Terminal. If you created it without a password you still need to allow the Terminal to open the session on your (the administrator's) behalf.

Comment: Try ssh user@server and see what happens

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `-I` as your parameter switch instead of `-i`? Most SSH versions I'm familiar with use the lower case i to specify the identity file to use for standard ssh keys, and uppercase I to specify a PKCS11 library.

Comment: it is a -i in lowercase... stupid dictionary :D I think the issue is the key is generated with putty and this format is not accepted in ssh

Comment: @JaviDR If you made a typo in the question, please use the edit link to fix it.